# ionic1, angularjs how to clear input fields using ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

Im stucked because of this problem, guys can you help me I'm just a student and this is for my thesis, in ionic1 framework I cant clear input fields from modal, when I close it and back again still the data I've inputted is encoded, any suggestions please...all answered is appreciated..

Comment: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), where is your code? what version of angular are you using, do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function when closing the modal that clean the inputs, to make it reusable you could just write the functions into a "utils" factory or something like that, passing the object as a param... Here's the simple solution function.

```
$scope.cleanFormInputs = function(){
    $scope.formObject = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.clearInput = function(){

$scope.inputname = ' ';

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to just put `cache-view="false"` in `ion-view`.

Like `<ion-view title="XYZ" cache-view="false">`

Hope this help:)

Answer (score 0):

Put these two inside your function for the input fields,

```
  $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
```